# How to assign a List<String> flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to assign a List of String in flutter like:

```
      List<String> names = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

error: The type 'List' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given. (wrong_number_of_type_arguments at line 90

error: A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'. (invalid_assignment at line 90

Why can't I assign a List like this?
What am I doing wrong here?
I have tried :

```
  String a = "A";
          String b = "B";
          String c = "C";
          List<String> names = [a, b, c]; 
It is still shwoing the same error.
I don't understand.
```

Comment: Give more information, i.e. the file/code context where error happens. I tested and don't have any error.

Comment: Create a complete, reproducible example.  I suspect you have some other class named `List`.

Comment: Yes. I looked into my code and it turned out had another```class List{ }```

Comment: And now you know why you must watch the filenames when you hover in your IDE.

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare an empty list with a name first and then later add values to the list.
Using
`listName.add()`

Comment: ```List<String> names=[];```. I have tried that. It says: Type List<dynamic> can't be assigned to a variable type of List

Comment: For fixed length and type:  List<String> myList = List<String>(3); ad for variable  type: var myList = List(3)